# Stopping Texmaker from moving the cursor from current line to another place of the document in errors

Tags: errors, texmaker

I've faced numerous times that Texmaker moves the cursor from the current line to the top of the document if there is a compilation error. Is there a way to stop this functionality?

EDIT: Texmaker now seems to move the cursor to the beginning of the next line, is there a way to stop this? Furthermore, depending on the nesting, Texmaker will move the cursor to an even different line.

Comment: I don't think there is a solution to this problem (at least in windows) but you can try this trick: add a dummy command to your command for exemple `...miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe" -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex |myname %.aux` this works for me.

Comment: @IrregularUser  Sorry i noticed that this doesn't work. I don't know why it did in the past.

Comment: @IrregularUser I add an answer please any comment or question are welcome.

Comment: @IrregularUser pdfviewer add.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a trick that can be helpful. The idea is to use a `.bat` file (I am under windows but this is not really important.)

Go to Options-> Configure texmaker

[image]

---

use the command of pdflatex

[image]
to build a .bat file here `mtpdftex.bat`

```
@echo off

D:/mtlatex/miktex/bin/pdflatex -interaction=nonstopmode %1
```

note here that `%.tex` is replaced with `%1`

---

**Update:** following comment [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/29589829#29589829)

the file `mtpdftex.bat` (check your disc C:)

```
@echo off

C:/Programmes/Miktex2.9/miktex/bin/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %1
```

you can even try

```
@echo off

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %1
```

---

Next use this bat in quick build of texmaker
[image]

---

**Update 2** One can add pdf view command to the quick build:
click  `wizard` Button of quick build and add pdf view

[image]

résult

[image]

Then edit this command by adding `D:/Nouveaudossier/mtpdftex.bat %.tex|` before

[image]

---

**Exemple** Quick build of this document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
bla bla bif \mt
\section{Foo}
\lipsum[1-4]
\section{Bar}
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

on click blue triangle (go to next error)
[image]

---

without error

[image]

on click blue triangle (go to next error)
[image]